# Sharepoint Online, Formatting column doest not work in web part

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sharepoint-online

i am already successed create some formatting column in sharepoint list. but when i am calling the list at web part, the formatting column does not work.
Please give some clue to solve it.

Thanks very much.

this is the captures of my formatting column
Work Fine :
[image]

did not worked in web part :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JSON formatting only works in modern experience. Your second picture looks like it is in the classic page. You can try to use the list/library web part in the modern page.

**Modern page:**
[image]
**Classic page:**
[image]

Comment: yes, i am still using classic page. 
is posible in modern page adding some script (JSON / Rest Api), or like content editor.
Thanks for your response.

Comment: In modern page,if you want to inject js/css ,you could use modern script editor web part.https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor

Comment: Or you could add SharePoint extension to inject css/js.https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/

Comment: Modern page has default list/library web part, you could import modern experience list/library directly.

Comment: how to import that experience ?

Comment: You could create a site page in SharePoint online site pages library.